# Lesson Plans for Digital Photography Courses

Tags: education

Our photography club is planning to provide instructor-led digital photography courses (e.g. Intro to Digital Photography, Intro to Lightroom, Intro to Photoshop, Intro to Portraiture, Intro to Landscapes, etc.).

Can anyone recommend a place where to get lesson plans for such courses? Preferably free, but paid is also OK. We're looking for "formal" lesson plans (e.g. in ROPES lesson plan format, etc.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.lynda.com - They offer a trial too, generally good resources and rather well priced. If you try them and like them during the trail you can continue however if they're not for you just stop.

I've used them in the past for coding work and touched a little bit with PS/LR.

Comment: OP isn't looking to take classes / lessons. They are looking for _lesson plans_ to create their own instructor-led courses.

Comment: I get that but wouldn't the best place to look at lessons plans be to check other places lessons?

Comment: If the lesson plans aren't made public, then not really. Maybe indirectly, at best. You have to essentially reverse-engineer the lesson plans from the lesson, by inferring what the actual lesson plan (i.e., _intent_) was.